# Can elephants trumpet when they have water in their trunks?

Tags: zoology

I am writing a fun story about elephants and want to know if elephants can trumpet or at least, make noises when they have water in their trunks, like when they are drinking water. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I think no. Because the elephant uses its trunk to make noise and if the trunk is filled with water then there is no chance the voice would come out.